# Express and create-react-app API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express

I'm running my create-react-app on `localhost:3000` I have a proxy set up in `package.json` to point to where my server is running (`localhost:3001`)

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
}
```

This is my `app.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    axios.post('/users')
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res) 
    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello</div>
  }
}
```

and in my `users.js` which doesn't even do anything:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

router.post('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  // empty body
}
```

Why am I getting a 404? And why is it trying to get the resource from `localhost:3000`? From my understanding, setting the proxy would allow the React app to talk to the Express server.

[image]

Note: the request worked with a GET, but I'm trying to do a POST request and this error only comes up with POST.

Edit: this is my (partial) config file for Express:

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

Comment: From my guess, you are running your react app on port 3000, but where do you run your express app? on which port?

Comment: because you put router.post('/') instead of router.post('/users')

Comment: Have you tested with Postman for POSTing to `/users` to see if your Express route actually works?

Comment: @NirBen-Yair my express app is running on 3001 - app.set('port', 3001);

Comment: Also, try putting something like `res.send('hello')` inside your route and see what happens. Having an empty route without responding will hang your request.

Comment: @ionizer I didn't get any response back in the Network response, and nothing logged either.

Comment: @patrickhuang94, as you said you are running your express app on 3001, the request in the console is going to 3000. Hence it will never find your `/users` route

Comment: @ivp that's what I'm trying to figure out - why is it routing to 3000 when I specified the proxy to point to 3001?

Answer (score 0):

React is by default redirecting you to port 3000 when it can't find the provided route on the proxy(which is localhost:3001).
I suppose you should use axios.post('/api/users') instead of what you are using now. 
I'm new to React, so I might get it wrong, but worth a try.